# SQL insert posted in wrong row order

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js

I am using node.js and mssql to post values from an embedded device to a SQL database. Each interval I increment a row ID and a sensor value and "insert" then to the database. However, when I view the database the rows appear to have been posted in the wrong order (see screenshot). Some of the missing entries appear much later.

I have debugged the code and the events are taking place in the correct order. So this is happening somewhere in the transaction.

The code is here:

```
var sql = require('mssql');     //sql 

var i = 0;

//database configuration
var config = {
   user: '*****',
   password: '******',
   server: '******', 
   database: '*******',

   options: {
      encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
   }
}

//main activity function to be called every 1 second
periodicActivity();

//setInterval function sets the period and function to be called
setInterval(function () { periodicActivity() }, 1000)

//
function periodicActivity() {    
    i = i + 1;
    var y = Math.random();

    var connection = new sql.Connection(config, function (err) {
        // ... error checks

       // Query       
       var request = new sql.Request(connection); 
       request.query('insert into SensorData (Id, data) values (' + i + ',' + y + ')', function (err, recordset) {
        // ... error checks
    });

});

//close the SQL connection
//connection.close();
}
```

The database screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Any help or suggestions very welcome.
Thanks,
T

Comment: Usually, if you do not specify an `ORDER BY` clause in your query, the rows will be returned in an arbitrary order, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: They don't appear to be in the "wrong" order, your screenshot appears to simply show them with no specific order. What happens if you order by `stamp`?

Comment: Does the table have a clustered index or any other index on it?

Comment: @ Adrian - I have been having problems with my "stamp". The format looks like this:
0x00000000000009AA
0x00000000000009AC
0x00000000000009AE
0x00000000000009B1
0x00000000000009B2
0x00000000000009B4
Does this look right to you?

Comment: @user3238504 You've switched hexadecimal view on. Other than that I can't see an issue.

Comment: @user3238504 Also, if you want the person you're @-ing to be notified, don't add the space after '@'.

Answer (score 0):

The insertion is probably done as you would expect. The data is just displayed in pseudorandom order caused by some internal thing. Order the data when selecting it and you are done.

Also, why not making the id a auto-incrementing primary key and then just make

```
request.query('insert into SensorData (data) values (' + y + ')', function (err, recordset) {
    // ... error checks
});
```

Comment: @ Martin - if I made the primary key auto-incrementing would that be increment at the time of my embedded device sending the data or at the server? (also how do you achieve this). At the moment I know they are out of order because the primary key is generated when the sample is measured. (I am a newbie!)

Comment: Oh, no worries. The auto-incrementation is done at the server by the sql database. It sounds like the best solution for you would be to create a new column - timestamp and send the data along with the precise time when it was measured. then you can just sort based on the timestamp and not worry about the insert order.

Comment: the device I am using to send the data does not have an accurate time, so I would prefer the server to stamp the data as it is entered. How do I command the server to do this in my query string? (Thank you for your help).

Comment: Oh, it actually rather easy. You create a column with datatype timestamp. Upon insertion of the data it will automatically insert the current time.

Comment: when I make the datatype timestamp I am seeing a hex string. I do not think there is enough information in the hex string for it to contain a date and time. The problem is though in Visual Studio I do not know how to change the "view" from showing this in hex? (See original screenshot).